# mock @patch does not patch redis class

Tags: python-3.x, redis, mocking

I'm trying to mock redis class using mockredis as show below. But the original redis class is not getting masked.

#### test_hitcount.py

```
import unittest
from mock import patch

import mockredis
import hitcount

class HitCountTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('redis.StrictRedis', mockredis.mock_strict_redis_client)
    def testOneHit(self):
        # increase the hit count for user peter
        hitcount.hit("pr")
        # ensure that the hit count for peter is just 1
        self.assertEqual(b'0', hitcount.getHit("pr"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

#### hitcount.py

```
import redis

r = redis.StrictRedis(host='0.0.0.0', port=6379, db=0)

def hit(key):
    r.incr(key)

def getHit(key):
    return (r.get(key))
```

Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: Can you include the import line for StrictRedis as it's written in `hitcount`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `import hitcount` module you build `redis.StrictRedis()` object and assign it to `r`. After this `import` every patch of `redis.StrictRedis` class cannot have effect on `r` reference at least you patch some `redis.StrictRedis`'s methods.

So what you need to do is patch `hitcount.r` instance. Follow (untested) code do the job by replace `hitcount.r` instance with your desired mock object:

```
@patch('hitcount.r', mockredis.mock_strict_redis_client(host='0.0.0.0', port=6379, db=0))
def testOneHit(self):
    # increase the hit count for user peter
    hitcount.hit("pr")
    # ensure that the hit count for peter is just 1
    self.assertEqual(b'0', hitcount.getHit("pr"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to patch the exact thing that you imported in `hitcount`.

So if you imported `import redis` in `hitcount` then you need to `@patch('hitcount.redis.StrictRedis')`.

If you imported `from redis import StrictRedis` then you need to `@patch('hitcount.StrictRedis')`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick answer @Simeon. Unfortunately, no luck at all :( still having the same effect after changing the patch as below  `@patch('hitcount.redis.StrictRedis', mockredis.mock_strict_redis_client)` <br/>

Comment: *So if you imported `import redis` in `hitcount` then you need to `@patch('hitcount.redis.StrictRedis')`*: this is not correct, in this case you can patch `redis.StrictRedis` also because `import redis` don't copy locally a reference to `redis.StrictRedis`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same issue. What I did is uninstall all the old versions of python from my machine. I used only python3 and it worked.
sudo apt-get remove python2.7
and I installed following
sudo easy_install3 pip
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools

and then it worked.